# Как сделать поиск по названию функций?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Есть сотни файлов в проекте вордпресс и есть функция create_machine. В каком файле она находится. Где искать??

Comment: `$ grep -r create_machine каталог` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я всегда решаю эту проблему с помощью VS Code.

1.) Устанавливаем на ПК (она бесплатна)

2.) Скачиваем все файлы сайта на локальный диск в отдельную папку.

3.) Открываем VS Code.

4.) Нажимаем Ctrl-O (Откроется окно выбора папки).

5.) Выбираем папку с файлами WordPress

6.) Нажимаем Ctrl-Shift-F (Появится строка поиска по содержимому файлов)

7.) Вводим create_machine и радуемся))

Если возможности скачать файлы нет - то почти во всех панелях управления хостингом есть функции поиска по содержимому файлов, но они работают очень медленно.